# Significado de "$" em .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Estou tentando entender o arquivo .htaccess do meu servidor porém, não acho referência bacanas na net, tenho a seguinte dúvida:
O que significa $ no .htaccess?

Alguém poderia me indicar um bom tutorial de .htaccess?

Comment: Em [RegExp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) `$` quer dizer final da _string_, mas pode ser outra coisa se não for RegExp aquilo a que te referes... Podes colocar a linha que tem o que procuras ver explicado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `.htaccess` utiliza expressões regulares para as configurações. O caractere `$` é uma âncora para delimitar o fim da `string` informada ou até a quebra de linha `\n`. O seu oposto é o caractere `^`, que combinará a ocorrência do início da `string` ou da linha.

Por exemplo, a seguinte expressão:

- `[0-9]$` : Buscará os dígitos entre `0` e `90` que estejam no fim de uma string ou da linha

Utilizando o `^`:

- `^[0-9]$` : Buscará somente o a string ou linha que inicie e termine com um dígito entre `0` e `9`

Answer (score 0):

Da documentação:

> Os arquivos .htaccess (ou "arquivos de configuração distribuída") oferecem um meio de fazer mudanças nas configurações por-diretório. Um arquivo, contendo uma ou mais diretrizes de configurações, é colocado em um diretório em particular, e as diretrizes se aplicam para aquele diretório e todos os seu subdiretórios subseqüentes.

Talvez a documentação do apache clarifique mais o conceito:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html